# stat_summary breaking factor ordering in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I have having a strange issue that might be a bug with `lubridate` or `ggplot`, where the factor ordering in a stacked bar chart (one factor for each day of the week) sometimes breaks when I add a `stat_summary` line. It seems to break when the first week of data only has one day to show, but works ok when there are more.

Let's say we have this data frame with ten days of data. I want each week to start on a Monday.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
df <- structure(list(perf_dt = structure(c(18032, 18033, 18034, 18035, 18036, 
                                     18037, 18039, 18040, 18041, 18042), class = "Date"), 
               n = c(32, 14, 55, 73, 39, 41, 44, 36, 71, 80), 
               week = structure(c(18035, 18035, 18035, 18035, 18042,
                                  18042, 18042, 18042, 18042, 18042), class = "Date")), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L)) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  mutate(cuml = cumsum(n),
         day_num = lubridate::wday(perf_dt, week_start = 1),
         day = lubridate::wday(perf_dt, label = T, week_start = 1)) %>%
  ungroup()

df
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   perf_dt        n week        cuml day_num day  
   <date>     <dbl> <date>     <dbl>   <dbl> <ord>
 1 2019-05-16    32 2019-05-19    32       4 Thu  
 2 2019-05-17    14 2019-05-19    46       5 Fri  
 3 2019-05-18    55 2019-05-19   101       6 Sat  
 4 2019-05-19    73 2019-05-19   174       7 Sun  
 5 2019-05-20    39 2019-05-26    39       1 Mon  
 6 2019-05-21    41 2019-05-26    80       2 Tue  
 7 2019-05-23    44 2019-05-26   124       4 Thu  
 8 2019-05-24    36 2019-05-26   160       5 Fri  
 9 2019-05-25    71 2019-05-26   231       6 Sat  
10 2019-05-26    80 2019-05-26   311       7 Sun
```

I can plot these in a stacked bar, using `stat_summary` to get the weekly total. This is how I want it.

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(week, n, fill = day)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = T)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::dollar(n), color = day), size = 3.5,
            position = position_stack(reverse = T, vjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, aes(label = scales::comma(..y..), group = week),
               vjust = -0.5, fontface = "bold", geom = "text") +
  scale_color_viridis_d(direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  guides(color = F)
```

[image]

But if I feed it data that starts on a Sunday, like May 19, AND I include the stat_summary layer, the ordering gets messed up, both in the stacking and in the legend. If I remove the `stat_summary` layer, it works fine, even starting on the Sunday.

Am I missing something in how this is set up which would make it work better? Is this is known bug in `lubridate` or `ggplot`? Is there a way to do this and keep the convenient & elegant `stat_summary` formulation?

```
# Same as above, but limited to dates starting May 19 and later
ggplot(df %>% filter(perf_dt >= ymd(20190519)),
       aes(week, n, fill = day)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = T)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::dollar(n), color = day), size = 3.5,
            position = position_stack(reverse = T, vjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, aes(label = scales::comma(..y..), group = week),
               vjust = -0.5, fontface = "bold", geom = "text") +
  scale_color_viridis_d(direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  guides(color = F)
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if / how that's applicable. I have an ordered factor that works as expected until I add `stat_summary` with the total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solutions

Move `fill = day` from `ggplot(aes(...))` into `geom_col(aes(...))`, since no other layer needs to inherit that anyway.

Alternatively, specifying the order of breaks by adding `limits = levels(df$day)` to `scale_fill_viridis_d(...)` also works.

## Explanation

When `fill = day` is included as one of the top-level aesthetic mappings in `ggplot()`, it is inherited by the `stat_summary` layer. This means that although the layer's chosen geom (`geom_text`) doesn't require a fill aesthetic, the mapping is included in the calculation of the layer's data.

When the full dataset `df` was used for the plot, this wasn't an issue, because summarising by week (the specified `group` variable) returns only NA values for day. The day column is then dropped completely from the layer data before any mapping to the fill scale is done.

When the subsetted `df` was used, however, summarising by week returns an NA value for the second week, but "Sun" for the first week, since there's now only one row of data associated with the first week. The layer data thus retains a fill column with two values: "Sun" and NA.

In the first case, the fill scale is constructed from the dataframes associated with the first two layers, which only have the values from `df$day`, and thus retain the original factor order.

in the second case, the fill scale is constructed from the dataframes associated with **all three layers**, which have the values from `df$day` plus NA. This screws up the factor order, so the scale defaults to alphabetical ordering.